# How Nginx can open all ASP files as text/html?

Tags: linux, nginx, asp, mime-type

I've a lot of files with ASP extension running on linux, but I can't rename. The content of that files is HTML, but when I open, the Nginx takes me to download.

Does anyone know what I can insert on Nginx to open ASP files as text/html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a MIME type with [`types`](http://nginx.org/r/types). This should appear *after* the line in `nginx.conf` which reads `include /etc/nginx/mime.types`:

```
http {
   ......
   types {
       text/html asp;
   }
   .....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the file is still downloaded.

Comment: It needs to appear after the existing mime types. Edited the answer. You should also specify any customizations you've done to the nginx configuration.

Comment: Yes, I had already inserted after mime.types include.

Comment: Sorry man, was cache. Your solution works! (:

Answer (score -1):

```
location ~* .(asp)$ {
      add_header Content-Type text/plain;}
```

Comment: This needs a better explanation.